# Replace a sentence more than once

Tags: bash, scripting, sed

I'm writing a bash script to generate CPP source files.
I have an list of variables and its names, like that:

```
   TH1F z_E;
   TH1F z_eta;
```

I want to turn in something like this:

```
   TH1F * z_E = (TH1F *)f->Get("z_E");
   TH2F * z_eta = (TH2F *)f->Get("z_eta");
```

I was trying to do it with `sed`, but I couldn't find a way to use the matched string do write the result.

PS: my `sed` version is 4.1.5

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
sed 's/\([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*\) *\([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*\);/\1 \2 = (\1 *)someOtherVar->Get("\2");/' input
```

Comment: so \1 mathes the first regular expression?

Comment: it refers to the first capture group, i.e., the match enclosed by the first `\(..\)`

Comment: BTW, its working right there are some kind of splitting before the "="

Comment: what do you mean splitting?

Comment: this is a real input `TH1F z_pt;` the output is `TH1F z_p t = (z_p *)f->Get("t");` it has a space before the last char of the varname and Get argument is wrong

Comment: I can't replicate it here, my output is `TH1F z_pt = (TH1F *)someOtherVar->Get("z_pt");`. Can you double check for copy/paste errors?

Comment: no copy paste error, I will edit the question with the real args

Comment: I tried your input using sed 4.1.5 but it still gives the expected output

Comment: my `\1` is matching with the all the chars of the varname except the last one and my ´\2´ is the last char the varname

Comment: what you say is only possible if you have a space in the character class, i.e., `[A-Za-z0-9_ ]` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: I'm running this in a CentOS 5.3. Unfortunately I don't have any space in the regex

Comment: I fount the problem, the separator of `TYPE varname` was an tab, not an space, so `[ \t\r]` for the more general case

Answer (score 0):

The final solution (solved minor problems with @perreal answer) were:

```
sed 's/\([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*\)[ \t]*\([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*\);/\1 \2 = (\1 *)f->Get("\2");/' input
```